# Salesforce updating metadata record using apex

Tags: salesforce, metadata, apex

'I am trying to update a salesforce metadata record via Apex. here is my code:

```html
Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();

 for(Omni_Routing_Skillset__mdt md: omnimetadata) {
    Metadata.CustomMetadata customMetadata = new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
      customMetadata.fullName = md.DeveloperName; //custom metadata name
    customMetadata.Label = md.MasterLabel;
      Metadata.CustomMetadataValue customField1 = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue(); //the values you're changing/updating
customField1.field = 'Omni_Routing_Skillset__mdt.Skill_Level__c'; //the custom field API Name that you're wanting to insert/update a value of
    customField1.value = skillsAndValues.get(md.MasterLabel);
      customMetadata.values.add(customField1);//add the changes to list of changes to be deployed
      mdContainer.addMetadata(customMetadata);
      System.debug('customMetadata: ' + customMetadata);

  }
  //MetadataDeploy callback = new MetadataDeploy();
  Id jobId = Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, null);
```

This kicks off the deployment but i get the following error:

```
**Must specify the name in the CustomMetadataType.CustomMetadata format, Current Name: Team_2_SEP, Required Delimiter: .**
```

I am not sure how to fix this, can anyone please advise?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The name would be Omni_Routing_Skillset__mdt.Team_2_SEP you're only passing in Team_2_SEP.

Comment: I did consider that and changed it but still got the same error, thanks for your input tho!

Answer (score 0):

You can reference this method:

```
public static void updateExisitingMetadatRecord() {

        List<Metadata_Creditional__mdt> metadatList = [SELECT Id, DeveloperName, 
        MasterLabel FROM Metadata_Creditional__mdt WHERE DeveloperName='MyTest'];
        Metadata.CustomMetadata metadataRec =  new Metadata.CustomMetadata();
        metadataRec.fullName = 
        'Metadata_Creditional__mdt.'+metadatList[0].DeveloperName;
        metadataRec.label = metadatList[0].MasterLabel;
        //provide the value for the fields and add it to custom metadata instance
        Metadata.CustomMetadataValue totalPurchasetoUpdate = new 
        Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
        totalPurchasetoUpdate.field = 'Secret_Key__c';
        totalPurchasetoUpdate.value = 'Change Secreet Value';
        metadataRec.values.add(totalPurchasetoUpdate);
        
        Metadata.DeployContainer mdContainer = new Metadata.DeployContainer();
        mdContainer.addMetadata(metadataRec);
        Metadata.Operations.enqueueDeployment(mdContainer, null);

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

customMetadata fullname should be your object's name (without the __mdt) + '.' + your record's DeveloperName:

```
customMetadata.fullName = 'IntegrationSettings.main';
```

customMetadata label should be your record's masterlabel:

```
customMetadata.label = 'main';
```

the fields are the usual __c field names (without the object name):

```
 Metadata.CustomMetadataValue theField = new Metadata.CustomMetadataValue();
    theField.field = 'AccessToken__c';
    theField.value = '123';
```